# Online contributions are marked as Pending (Incomplete transaction) status

Tags: paypal, ipn, pending

Whenever any user makes donation using Paypal payment option, it does not auto complete the payment in CiviCRM contribution dashboard. It shows it as "Pending (Incomplete Transaction)" status.

This was working (was marking the contribution with complete status) till May 2016 end, since June 2016 begining it stopped marking contribution to Completed status.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what's being described here is a particular case of CiviCRM issue [financial/27](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/27) - PayPal Standard doesn't handle IPNs.  The issue mentions recurring payments, but any payment involving an IPN is likely affected.

You can help solve this by testing [the proposed fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12387) and reporting on whether it solves your problem, creates new problems, etc.

Note also that this sounds related to the same section of code improved in [financial/14](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues/14) which deals specifically with PayPal Express.  You may want to see if upgrading to Civi 5.3.0 helps matters.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem since upgrading to 4.7.3 and beyond. What I found is the IPN is sending the wrong path to Paypal, so that Paypal cannot update.

This is a response from paypal themselves:
Verify that the server is generating automatic Paypal payment notifications (IPN). The IPN sent to this URL have failed :

http:///components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php?reset=1&contactID=3&contributionID=3&module=contribute

Basically it is looking under components and not under administrator/components.

Here's what i am trying - I created the path/file under components.

I'm trying that now. I figure if it can't find the file because the wrong path is specified, I'll copy the file there where it wants it to be.
If I knew where to fix the error I would - does anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

I have to keep removing the following from
public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/extern/ipn.php

Remove the following two lines in ipn.php:
  //CRM-18245

if ($config->userFramework == 'Joomla') {

```
CRM_Utils_System::loadBootStrap();
```

Every time there is an update, these two lines screw up my Paypal IPNs.

Comment: You might want to comment on the CRM-18245 if the patch is not working for you

Comment: I still have to remove this patch even running in 4.7.11.

Comment: I added a comment to JIRA saying it still knocks my ipn's out.  I just have no idea why.